# How to use pre-populated sqlite database in nativescript-sidekick using Javascript project

Tags: javascript, sqlite, nativescript

I am currently trying to connect to a pre-populated Sqlite database in NativeScript-Sidekick using a **JavaScript** Project. I have gone through so many tutorials and videos but they all include **Angular**. Is there any code that allows a **JavaScript** project to interact with the database? Such as allowing the **TextField** to be filled by the contents pulled in the **SELECT** based on the column they are in?

Here is my code so far from tutorials and the like, however they did use **Telerik**:

**This is the home-items-page.xml**

```
<Page
navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo"  
xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">

<StackLayout>
    <TextField id="firstname" hint="Fist Name" text="{{ firstname }}"/>
    <TextField id="lastname" hint="Last Name" text="{{ lastname }}" />
    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
        <Button text="Insert" tap="{{ insert }}" />
        <Button text="Select" tap="{{ select }}" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
</Page>
```

**home-items-page.js**

```
var createViewModel = require("./home-items-view-model").createViewModel;
var Sqlite = require("nativescript-sqlite");

function onNavigatingTo(args) {
var page = args.object;
if (!Sqlite.exists("eatforlife.db")) {
Sqlite.copyDatabase("eatforlife.db");
}

var db_name = "eatforlife.db";

new Sqlite(db_name).then(db => {
    page.bindingContext = createViewModel(db);
});

}

exports.onNavigatingTo = onNavigatingTo;
```

**home-items-view-model**

```
const observableModule = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");
var Sqlite = require("nativescript-sqlite");

function createViewModel(db) {
var viewModel = Observable();

viewModel.firstname = "";
viewModel.lastname = "";

    viewModel.select = function(){
    db.all("SELECT * FROM client WHERE Email = ? AND Password = ?",["example@gmail.com","qwerty123"]).then(rows => {
        for(var row in rows){
            console.log("RESULT ", rows[row]);

        }
    }, error =>{
        console.log("SELECT ERROR",error);
    })
    }

return viewModel;
}

exports.createViewModel = createViewModel;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use the [getter and setter](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/observable#creating-observable-with-fromobject-method) methods on Observable, something like

```
viewModel.set("firstname", YourFirstNameFromDB);
viewModel.set("lastname", YourLastNameFromDB);
```

Assuming you want to get a single row from DB, you may use [get](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-sqlite#dbget) method instead of all.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. Would that be inside the select function or should I edit the    viewModel.firstname = "";
    viewModel.lastname = "";

Comment: That should be actually both. Set an initial value (empty string) above select, inside select assign the actual values.

Comment: So right now I would test it out but the `Sqlite.copyDatabase("eatforlife.db");` is copying an empty database. Or rather it is filling the variables as blanks or " " instead of the set variables. Do you know what would be the cause of this?

Comment: I'm unable to help here until I have access to code. If you can create a Playground sample, I would be happy to take a look.

Comment: Everything is as above though

Comment: I don't find the insert function in the above code. Also I believe you must have made some fixes on the view model now, so it better to have a Playground setup to make sure we are on same page.

Comment: I got the database working properly now. It was the fact that the database was **.db** instead of **.sqlite**. I just had to change that. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I got the **Textfields** to change on **tap** to **SQLite** data using the **Observables**

**Updated home-items-page.js**

```
var createViewModel = require("./home-items-view-model").createViewModel;
var Sqlite = require("nativescript-sqlite");

function onNavigatingTo(args) {
var page = args.object;

if (!Sqlite.exists("eatforlife.sqlite")) {
 Sqlite.copyDatabase("eatforlife.sqlite");
}

var db_name = "eatforlife.sqlite";

new Sqlite(db_name).then(db => {
    page.bindingContext = createViewModel(db);
 });

}

exports.onNavigatingTo = onNavigatingTo;
```

**Updated home-items-view-model.js**

```
const Observable = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable").Observable;
const fromObject = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable").fromObject;

const fromObjectRecursive = require("tns-core- 
modules/data/observable").fromObjectRecursive;

var dialogs = require("tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs");
var Sqlite = require("nativescript-sqlite");

function createViewModel(db) {
 var viewModel = new Observable();


viewModel.select = function () {
    db.get("SELECT * FROM client").then(rows => {

        viewModel.set("setname", rows[10]);
        viewModel.set("setsurname",rows[11]);

        viewModel.set("name",this.get("setname"));
        viewModel.set("surname", this.get("setsurname"));

    }, error => {
        console.log("SELECT ERROR", error);
    });
  }

 return viewModel;
}

exports.createViewModel = createViewModel;
```

**Updated home-items-page.xml**

```
<Page
 navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo"  
 xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">

<StackLayout>
    <Label id="name" text="{{ name }}"/>
    <Label id="surname" text="{{ surname }}" />
    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
        <Button text="Insert" tap="{{ insert }}" />
        <Button text="Select" tap="{{ select }}" />
     </StackLayout>
 </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

I hope this is of use to many others and thanks to **Manoj**